# Can't use aggregate functions in the WHERE clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Running this query in cypher

```
MATCH (v:Person)<--(a:Place)<--(s:Thing) WHERE count(s)>0 RETURN v
```

Getting this Error Message:

```
Can't use aggregate functions in the WHERE clause.
```

Obviously it doesn't like filtering on the count aggregate function.  What is a good work around for this?  Thanks!

Comment: Try `MATCH (v:Person)<--(a:Place)<--(s:Thing) WITH count(s) as thingCount WHERE thingCount>0 RETURN v`

Comment: doesn't recognize v, tried adding v into WITH and numbers came out as all 1

Comment: Try a dinstinct count. See [1.9 refcard](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guys almost had it in the comments.

```
MATCH (v:Person)<--(a:Place)<--(s:Thing) 
RETURN count(s) as count, v
```

If this is what is returning 1 counts for everything, are you sure you have more than one thing per person? You don't need to check that the count is > 0, because that is implied.